# Command line: rostopic pub - why is required specify a topic type?

Tags: ros, rostopic--pub

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unsure why i must specify a rostopic **type**, while invoke a `rostopic pub` command.

```
rostopic pub /topic type [args...]
```

I think, that a message type can be deduced by internal call a `rostopic info` on a *rostopic name*.

So, after all you can improve your rosbash file to deduct the topic type

```
# rosbash
778 pub)
779         if [[ $COMP_CWORD == 2 ]]; then
780                 opts=`rostopic list 2> /dev/null`
781                 COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${arg}))
782         elif [[ $COMP_CWORD == 3 ]]; then
783                 opts=`_msg_opts ${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}`
784                 COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${arg}))
```

changing the line 783 to:

```
opts=`rostopic info ${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD-1]} | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

or after mig advice:

```
opts=`rostopic info ${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD-1]} 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ -z $opts ]; then
    opts=`_msg_opts ${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}`
fi
```

Please correct my misunderstanding about a rostopic pub.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246277/command-line:-rostopic-pub---why-is-required-specify-a-topic-type?/) by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will only work if the topic is already registered. Even though the idea is, in general, valid, if you want to do a `rostopic pub` on a topic that has no publishers or subscribers so far, this deduction will fail.
I guess this is why the choice has been to include this.

You could obvisously try to include this as well and set up a PR.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2016-10-24**:
Ok, to protect against no registered topic you can easly improve snippet to:

```
opts=`rostopic info ${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD-1]} 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ -z $opts ]; then
    opts=`_msg_opts ${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}`
fi
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-17**:
[PR](https://github.com/ros/ros/pull/125) was opened and merged.